# Redux reducer being called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm developing React Native application using Redux.

The application has Registration screen with a simple form:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Alert,
    Button,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {register} from "../redux/actions/Registration";
import {REGISTER} from "../redux/constants/ActionTypes";
import Loader from "./Loader";

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        isLoggedIn: state.registration.isLoggedIn,
        token: state.registration.token,
        isLoading: state.common.isLoading,
        error: state.common.error
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onRegister: (username, password, firstName, lastName) => {
            dispatch(register(username, password, firstName, lastName));
        }
    }
};

@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export default class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            route: REGISTER,
            email: '',
            password: '',
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            isLoading: false
        }
    }

    register(e) {
        this.props.onRegister(
            this.state.email,
            this.state.password,
            this.state.firstName,
            this.state.lastName
        );
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.props.error != null && this.props.error !== undefined && this.props.error !== '') {
            setTimeout(() => Alert.alert(this.props.error), 600);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {isLoading} = this.props;

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.registration_form} behaviour="padding">

                    <Loader loading={isLoading}/>

                    <TextInput style={styles.text_input} placeholder="First Name" placeholderTextColor="white"
                               underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
                               onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({firstName: text})}/>
                    <TextInput style={styles.text_input} placeholder="Last Name" placeholderTextColor="white"
                               underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
                               onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({lastName: text})}/>
                    <TextInput style={styles.text_input} placeholder="Email" placeholderTextColor="white"
                               underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} keyboardType="email-address"
                               onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})}/>
                    <TextInput style={styles.text_input} placeholder="Password" placeholderTextColor="white"
                               underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
                               onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
                               secureTextEntry={true}/>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={(e) => this.register(e)}>
                        <Text style={styles.btn_text}>Sign up</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <Button buttonStyle={{marginTop: 40}}
                            backgroundColor="transparent"
                            textStyle={{color: "#fff"}}
                            title="Login"
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}/>

                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#36485f',
        paddingLeft: 60,
        paddingRight: 60
    },
    registration_form: {
        alignSelf: 'stretch',

    },
    text_input: {
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        height: 40,
        marginBottom: 30,
        color: '#fff',
        borderBottomColor: '#f8f8f8',
        borderBottomWidth: 1
    },
    button: {
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#59cbbd',
        marginTop: 30
    },
    btn_text: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
});
```

Also, I've created actions:

1) `Common.js`

```
import {FAILED, LOADING} from "../constants/ActionTypes";


export const loading = (isLoading) => {
    return {
        type: LOADING,
        isLoading: isLoading
    }
};

export const failed = (error) => {
    return {
        type: FAILED,
        error: error
    }
};
```

2) `Registration.js`:

```
import {userService} from "../../service/UserService";
import {REGISTER} from "../constants/ActionTypes";
import {failed, loading} from "./Common";

export const register = (username, password, firstName, lastName) => {
    return dispatch => {

        dispatch(loading(true));

        userService.register(username, password, firstName, lastName)
            .then(resp => {
                    dispatch(loading(false));

                    dispatch({
                        type: REGISTER,
                        token: resp.json().token,
                        error: null
                    });
                }
            )
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch(loading(false));
                dispatch(failed(err.message))
            })
    };
};
```

And reducers:

1) `Common.js`:

```
import {FAILED, LOADING, REGISTER} from "../constants/ActionTypes";

const defaultState = {
    isLoading: false,
    error: null
};

export default function reducer(state = defaultState, action) {
    console.log('COMMON STATE: ', state);
    console.log('COMMON ACTION: ', action);

    switch (action.type) {
        case LOADING:
            return {
                ... state,
                isLoading: action.isLoading
            };
        case FAILED:
            return {
                ... state,
                error: action.error
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

2) `Registration.js`:

```
import {FAILED, LOADING, REGISTER} from "../constants/ActionTypes";

const defaultState = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    token: null
};

export default function reducer(state = defaultState, action) {
    console.log('REGISTER STATE: ', state);
    console.log('REGISTER ACTION: ', action);

    switch (action.type) {
        case REGISTER:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isLoggedIn: action.isLoggedIn,
                token: action.token
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

3) `Index.js`:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import registration from './Registration';
import login from './Login';
import common from './Common'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    registration,
    login,
    common
});

export default rootReducer;
```

When I click "Sign up" button on Register component for the first time - everything ok - it shows a spinner and then one alert.

When I click "Sign up" button for the second time (or third, etc), it also shows a spinner and then it opens two alerts one by one.

What I expect: on each click application should show only one alert.

In console I see the following output:

```
10:27:07 PM: REGISTER STATE:  Object {
10:27:07 PM:   "isLoggedIn": false,
10:27:07 PM:   "token": null,
10:27:07 PM: }
10:27:07 PM: REGISTER ACTION:  Object {
10:27:07 PM:   "isLoading": false,
10:27:07 PM:   "type": "LOADING",
10:27:07 PM: }
10:27:07 PM: LOGIN STATE:  Object {
10:27:07 PM:   "isLoggedIn": false,
10:27:07 PM:   "token": null,
10:27:07 PM: }
10:27:07 PM: LOGIN ACTION:  Object {
10:27:07 PM:   "isLoading": false,
10:27:07 PM:   "type": "LOADING",
10:27:07 PM: }
10:27:07 PM: COMMON STATE:  Object {
10:27:07 PM:   "error": "Network request failed",
10:27:07 PM:   "isLoading": true,
10:27:07 PM: }
10:27:07 PM: COMMON ACTION:  Object {
10:27:07 PM:   "isLoading": false,
10:27:07 PM:   "type": "LOADING",
10:27:07 PM: }
10:27:07 PM: REGISTER STATE:  Object {
10:27:07 PM:   "isLoggedIn": false,
10:27:07 PM:   "token": null,
10:27:07 PM: }
10:27:07 PM: REGISTER ACTION:  Object {
10:27:07 PM:   "error": "Network request failed",
10:27:07 PM:   "type": "FAILED",
10:27:07 PM: }
10:27:07 PM: LOGIN STATE:  Object {
10:27:07 PM:   "isLoggedIn": false,
10:27:07 PM:   "token": null,
10:27:07 PM: }
10:27:07 PM: LOGIN ACTION:  Object {
10:27:07 PM:   "error": "Network request failed",
10:27:07 PM:   "type": "FAILED",
10:27:07 PM: }
10:27:07 PM: COMMON STATE:  Object {
10:27:07 PM:   "error": "Network request failed",
10:27:07 PM:   "isLoading": false,
10:27:07 PM: }
10:27:07 PM: COMMON ACTION:  Object {
10:27:07 PM:   "error": "Network request failed",
10:27:07 PM:   "type": "FAILED",
10:27:07 PM: }
```

So reducers being called two times. How to fix this? Or how to prevent opening the second alert popup?

**UPDATE.**

You can find the source code of the project on GitHub: https://github.com/YashchenkoN/money-observer-client

**UPDATE 2.**
After changes from @Chase DeAnda it looks in this way:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `register` function you need to check `props` to determine if the user is already registered or not:

```
register(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!this.props.token) {
    this.props.onRegister(
      this.state.email,
      this.state.password,
      this.state.firstName,
      this.state.lastName
    );
  } else {
    // User already registered
    // Redirect to login page
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Ah okay, I think I see the problem now. You are using the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. This method gets called **everytime** a piece of state or **props** get passed down to it, not necessarily only if they have changed. The problem your running in to is that you are not checking if `this.props.error` is actually different than the first error you already displayed. Change it to:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
    if(prevProps.error !== this.props.error && this.props.error){
        setTimeout(() => Alert.alert(this.props.error), 600);
    }
}
```

Since you have multiple reducers reacting to the failed XHR request, your component will get props passed to it from multiple actions. You need to make sure to only display the error if it's different than what was previously passed in.

Comment: I don't need a redirect in my case. Register function is being called only one time and looks good (as for me). The problem is with redux, since it's calling reducers more than one time

Comment: The register api call is failing as seen here: `REGISTER ACTION:  Object {
 "error": "Network request failed",
 "type": "FAILED"}`

Comment: Yes, I know. In case of error it should open alert. The problem is that it opens 2 alerts instead of 1

Comment: Tried your code - it didn't help. Now, when I click button for the first time it shows alert, but when I clink for the second time - it doesn't show alert at all

Comment: Okay, your requirements are very unclear. At this point I have no idea what you are expecting. I hope what I was able to provide helped. Good luck.

Comment: Anyway, thank for help!
Also I've updated a post to include GIF of how it looks after your changes. If you have a chance, please take a look

Comment: @MykolaYashchenko You need a way to track each error. The problem is that you have multiple dispatches happening when it errors out. That is causing multiple updates to your component. The fix I put in was to only show the error if the **text** is different. What you can do to fix this is add an `id` to each error message. Then, you can change the if check I provided to look at `if(this.props.error.id !== prevProps.error.id)` instead of just checking if the text is different.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent calling multiple dispatches?

Comment: Yeah you just need to clean up your actions. I'm not sure what is triggering what though, you'll have to step through your code. My hunch is that it has something to do with the `COMMON` reducer though.

Comment: I see 5 `"error": "Network request failed"` actions being dispatched in your log. There should only be one per button click.